# Fill parent by setting children height percentage

Tags: css

I have 2 columns. The first column is higher. The second column has 3 fieldsets. I'd like to fill the second column by setting children height percentage but it doesn't work. The second column height must equal the first column height. How to do it?

[JSFiddle HERE](http://goo.gl/cXjWHJ)

Update:

I tried to set parent height but the third fieldset went out of the secondColumn.

[JSFiddle HERE](http://goo.gl/WhPQZQ)

Comment: setting height as a percentage only works if you have a relative parent. Since your parent's height isn't set, nothing happens. Try setting a height to your `container` div?

Comment: Do you want the height of both columns to be large enough for the content of the larger of the two, or for both columns to fill the entire height of the page? http://jsfiddle.net/Q3D45/13/ demonstrates filling the entire page.

Comment: Not entire the page. They should fill the container. secondColumn height should follow firstColumn height.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of approaching this problem using CSS table cells.

For you HTML, add a wrapper `div` in the short (right most) column:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="firstColumn">
        CONTENT<br>
        CONTENT<br>
        CONTENT<br>
        CONTENT<br>
        ...
        CONTENT<br>
    </div>
    <div id="secondColumn">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <fieldset id="first">
            <legend>TEST1</legend>
            Content
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="second">
            <legend>TEST2</legend>
            Content
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="third">
            <legend>TEST3</legend>
            Content
        </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the CSS, try the following:

```css
#container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

#firstColumn {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#secondColumn {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    outline: 2px dotted blue;
}
legend {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
#first {
    height: 15%;
}

#second {
    height: 25%;
}

#third {
    height: 45%;
}
```

Apply `display: table` to the parent `#container`, and `display: table-cell` to the child elements `#firstColumn` and `#secondColumn`.  Set the height to 100% for the table and the table-cell elements.

For the `.wrapper`, set the height to 100% so that it fills up the height of the 
column, and then adjust the heights of the fieldset elements.

Note that you need to allow some vertical space for the legend (I assumed 5%) so that
15% + 25% + 45% + 3x5% = 100%, this should be close to what you need.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/qs25d/

Note: You may want to set a min-height to the parent (table) container to make sure
that the three fields sets have enough room, otherwise you may not get the vertical
height proportions as you expected for the fieldsets.